# iOS 5, 6 Twitter login: open web login when account is not configured

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter-oauth

I'm building an iOS app that implements Twitter sign-in.
I have a separate server-side token for my app, so I'm implementing reverse-auth as explained in [Twitter's developers' guide](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth).

To achieve this, I'm using [Sean Cook's implementation](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample).
Everything's working fine, but I'm wondering what would be the optimal implementation for when the user does not have a registered account in settings.
For now, I've created a SLComposeViewController (hide view and keyboard) to show "No Twitter Accounts" alert view which gives the options of "cancel" and "settings".

But I think that it'd be better if the app opens up safari to twitter's sign-in page and redirects immediately afterwards to my app. (if successfully signed-in)

1. How would I implement this? I can't seem to find good examples.
2. Which of the two solutions is better in your opinion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't hijack twitter's page and make it do something it is not designed to do.  That is why the sign in library exists in the first place.